# 2001 honda civic dx over heating problem

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

Two of my hoses in the front are very hard I took out the thermostat and the hoses are still hard and my car is still over heating what can it be

Comment: If you take off the coolant expansion tank cap while starting the car, does the coolant bubble inside (only do this with a cold engine)? Do you lose coolant over time?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do the fans run? Do you know anything about the condition of the water pump?

Comment: When you say hard, do you mean they feel like they are under a lot of pressure inside?  Does the expansion tank pressure cap release the pressure and blow water out when it over-heats?  Is the dashboard temperature gauge showing high temperature?

Comment: There are a couple common scenarios  to overheating.  overheating while stopped/low speed is typically fans.  Overheating while on the highway is typically a small leak or a clog in the radiator.  Other possibilities are a bad water pump or bad head gasket.  Are you loosing coolant?

Comment: This person has not returned to the site. Without extra info as requested this should just be closed as unclear